# how to get values from an array in which array is in name value pair-PHP

Tags: php, php-5.3

Json Decode,

```
{"3C0DE946-3E0F-A924-F1C8-1FA723A23299":"apple","D6E3D33B-ED3E-7CE1-365F-321DA17540A0":"mango"}
```

I want to print the key and value seperatly from this array .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of **`json_decode()`**

```
<?php
$str='{"3C0DE946-3E0F-A924-F1C8-1FA723A23299":"apple","D6E3D33B-ED3E-7CE1-365F-321DA17540A0":"mango"}';
$str=json_decode($str);

print_r($str);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not a php array, that a small portion of JSON. To handle it in PHP you can do the followin:

```
<?php
    $json  = '{"3C0DE946-3E0F-A924-F1C8-1FA723A23299":"apple","D6E3D33B-ED3E-7CE1-365F-321DA17540A0":"mango"}';
    $array = json_decode($json, 1);

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        echo "Key - $key\nValue - $value\n\n";
    }
```

#### Output:

```
Key - 3C0DE946-3E0F-A924-F1C8-1FA723A23299
Value - apple

Key - D6E3D33B-ED3E-7CE1-365F-321DA17540A0
Value - mango
```